# C#/.NET is there a way to know which property in an object changed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Basically I have a .NET Web API, and depending on which property in an object is being updated on a `put` route, I want to execute certain code blocks before the database changes are applied.

Is there any faster way to do this than:

1. the api endpoint receives the updated object,
2. we get the original object from the db
3. we cycle through the properties and compare each one to track a list of changed properties?
4. we execute code blocks depending on which properties were changed;
5. we finally pass the updated object to the database for a savechangesAsync call.

Comment: What about telling the user to only PUT the fields they _want_ changed, rather than all of them which may or may not be modified?

Comment: It looks like you want PATCH, not PUT.

Comment: REST APIs are specifically stateless so the only way to tell what has changed is to retrieve the original value from the data store and compare them. The alternative is to ask the caller of the API to tell you shat has changed, or only submit the changes.

Comment: [JSON Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) is a PATCH request body format that specifies *how* to change the resource, rather than just being a partial overlay of the properties to change.